# ¿Cómo insertar array en tabla de MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Necesito migrar un archivo JSON que tiene los datos de mis *users* a una tabla de MySQL con PHP, ya hice la conexión, con la base de datos pude crear la tabla y pude decodificar el JSON a un array. Lo que no puedo hacer es insertar los datos del array a la tabla de usuarios en MySQL.

Mi JSON se ve algo así:

```
{
    "nombre":"asudhau",
    "apellido":"uhsaudhau",
    "pass":"$2y$10$KAg3wt7bBjphgdCNJf4VXe.an8lOnlOvWVdVsh2Qsws0dbhWiDwkO",
    "mail":"usaudha@hotmail.com",
    "sexo":"F",
    "id":34,
    "nacimiento":"2016-10-06"
}
{
    "nombre":"abudasd",
    "apellido":"hasdua",
    "pass":"$2y$10$c781KdL3ERgDCnP6MR28xuf\/dnKjuVajklc0uSj2FnBrZSB1H88Si",
    "mail":"uhasiuda@hotmail.com",
    "sexo":"F",
    "id":35,
    "nacimiento":"1990-02-03"
}
{
    "nombre":"audihaiudh",
    "apellido":"uiahsdiuahdi",
    "pass":"$2y$10$Q7VjafKxt\/kuJS1BrslF0uSZPwHe7Hvp6olMxetgY31KcmMT9dIo2",
    "mail":"hiuahdiuah@hotmail.com",
    "sexo":"F",
    "id":36,
    "nacimiento":"1999-02-03"
}
```

Así llegué a los valores de cada *user*:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dh_usuarios;charset=UTF8mb4', 'root', '');
   $jsondata = file_get_contents('../usuarios.json');
   $usuariosArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $jsondata);

    foreach ($usuariosArray as $usuario) {
      $jsondata = json_decode($usuario.PHP_EOL, true);
      $jsonarray[] = array($jsondata);
    }
      foreach ($jsonarray as $row) {

      $nombre = $row[0]['nombre'];
      $apellido = $row[0]['apellido'];
      $pass = $row[0]['pass'];
      $mail = $row[0]['mail'];
      $sexo = $row[0]['sexo'];
      $id = $row[0]['id'];
      $nacimiento = $row[0]['nacimiento'];
}
```

Ahora quiero insertarlos en una tabla que ya tengo creada en MySQL y no sabría cómo hacerlo...

Intenté con esto, pero no se insertan.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
    INSERT INTO dh_usuarios(nombre, apellido, pass, mail, sexo, id, nacimiento)
    VALUES(:nombre, :apellido, :pass, :mail, :sexo, :id, :nacimiento);
   ');

  $stmt->execute([
    ':nombre' => $nombre,
    ':apellido' => $apellido,
    ':pass' => $pass,
    ':mail' => $mail,
    ':sexo' => $sexo,
    ':id' => $id,
    ':nacimiento' => $nacimiento,
  ]
);
```

Comment: ¿Recibes algún error? De paso, te felicito por no concatenar los valores directamente al SQL. Es refrescante.

Comment: no me tira ningun error... pero no se insertan a la base :(

Comment: ¿Como verificas que nada se inserta? ¿Que tal si intentas hacer un `select` en tu código para leer el registro después del insert, ¿lee el registro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al final cambie la forma de insertarlos con la ayuda de los que me respondieron, y pude crearlo asi

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dh_usuarios";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$jsondata = file_get_contents('../usuarios.json');
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsondata, true);


foreach ($jsonarray as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $apellido = $row['apellido'];
    $mail = $row['mail'];
    $pass = $row['pass'];
    $sexo = $row['sexo'];
    $nacimiento = $row['nacimiento'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nombre, apellido, email, pass, sexo, nacimiento)
        VALUES($id, '$nombre', '$apellido', '$mail', '$pass', '$sexo', '$nacimiento')";
        $conn->query($sql);
 }
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Intenta con esto:

```
    [// <-- Agregar este tag al inicio
    {
      "nombre":"asudhau",
      "apellido":"uhsaudhau",
      "pass":"$2y$10$KAg3wt7bBjphgdCNJf4VXe.an8lOnlOvWVdVsh2Qsws0dbhWiDwkO",
      "mail":"usaudha@hotmail.com",
      "sexo":"F",
      "id":34,
      "nacimiento":"2016-10-06"
     },
     {
      "nombre":"abudasd",
      "apellido":"hasdua",
     "pass":"$2y$10$c781KdL3ERgDCnP6MR28xuf\/dnKjuVajklc0uSj2FnBrZSB1H88Si",
     "mail":"uhasiuda@hotmail.com",
     "sexo":"F",
     "id":35,
     "nacimiento":"1990-02-03"
     },
     {
     "nombre":"audihaiudh",
     "apellido":"uiahsdiuahdi",
     "pass":"$2y$10$Q7VjafKxt\/kuJS1BrslF0uSZPwHe7Hvp6olMxetgY31KcmMT9dIo2",
     "mail":"hiuahdiuah@hotmail.com",
     "sexo":"F",
     "id":36,
     "nacimiento":"1999-02-03"
     }
     ]// <-- Agregar este tag al final
```

Luego en PHP:

```
    $conn = new   
     PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dh_usuarios;charset=UTF8mb4', 'root',             

     '');
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('../usuarios.json');
    $usuariosArray = json_decode($jsondata, true);


  foreach ($usuariosArray as $row) {

  $nombre = $row['nombre'];
  $apellido = $row['apellido'];
  $pass = $row['pass'];
  $mail = $row['mail'];
  $sexo = $row['sexo'];
  $id = $row['id'];
  $nacimiento = $row['nacimiento'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO dh_usuarios(nombre, apellido, pass,      
                          mail, sexo, id, nacimiento)
                          VALUES(:nombre, :apellido, :pass, :mail, :sexo,   
                          :id, :nacimiento);
                         ');

    $stmt->execute([':nombre' => $nombre,
                  ':apellido' => $apellido,
                  ':pass' => $pass,
                  ':mail' => $mail,
                  ':sexo' => $sexo,
                  ':id' => $id,
                  ':nacimiento' => $nacimiento
                 ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el acceso e inserción a la base de datos se da después de recorrer el bucle por lo tanto las variables `nombre, apellido , email etc` . no tienen valores , debería colocar el proceso dentro del foreach , adempas se podría usar bind para pasar los datos recogidos por el array

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('file.json');
$usuariosArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $jsondata);

foreach ($usuariosArray as $usuario) {
  $jsondata = json_decode($usuario.PHP_EOL, true);
  $jsonarray[] = array($jsondata);
}
  foreach ($jsonarray as $row) {

  $nombre = $row[0]['nombre'];
  $apellido = $row[0]['apellido'];
  $pass = $row[0]['pass'];
  $mail = $row[0]['mail'];
  $sexo = $row[0]['sexo'];
  $id = $row[0]['id'];
  $nacimiento = $row[0]['nacimiento'];
  $data = array('nombre'=> $nombre, 'apellido'=> $apellido, 'password'=> $pass, 'mail'=> $mail,'sexo'=> $sexo, 'id'=> $id, 'nacimiento'=> $nacimiento);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO dh_usuarios
  (nombre, apellido, pass, mail, sexo, id, nacimiento) VALUES
  (:nombre, :apellido, :password, :sexo, :id, :nacimiento)');
  $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, pero sigue sin insertarse a la tabla..., no se si estare escribiendo mal la parte de stmt, o si los values no se estan ejecutando bien y no se graban... :(, estoy probando con fetch, pero no se  si lo estoy escribiendo bien.... T_T

Comment: Actualizé mi respuesta espero le ayude. no dude en preguntar si tiene alguna duda.

Comment: ahora me tira error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()

Comment: Error mio, probar con la actualización .

Comment: T_____T debo ser yo, porque error ahora no me tira, pero no se me insertan los datos en la tabla... :(

Comment: @MarcosGallardo - Por favor no intentes de corregir la respuesta de esta manera: *Esta edición se aparta de la intención original de la publicación. Incluso aquellas ediciones que implican grandes cambios deben esmerarse para preservar los objetivos del propietario de la publicación.*

Answer (score 0):

Valida que los tipos de datos que intentes insertar sean los que estén permitidos en los campo.

Es decir, puede que en el json este un email de 15 caracteres y la base de datos solo permita solo 10, o que la pass solo permita datos enteros y le estes pasado un string, eso suele pasar muy seguido

valida el tipo de dato, la longitud y si no permite campos nullos.

Por lo general esto es considerado error capa 8 y supongo que no se te muestra ningún error de referencia